# Click event not emitted when mousedown/mouseup do add/removeClass on element

Tags: javascript, firefox, safari, dom-events

I'm attaching `mousedown`, `mouseup` and `click` handlers to an element. On `mousedown` I add a class to the element, on `mouseup` I remove the class, and on `click` I do some work. (This is a simplification of the context. In my project the `click` event is handled by a 3rd party component.)

The problem I'm having is that the **`click` event is never emitted** in Safari and Firefox, but it works just fine in Chrome. (I don't know what IE does. I don't have access to it, and don't care about it.)

The code is as follows:

HTML:

```
<div id="clickme">
    <div class="normal"></div>
    <div class="highlight"></div>
</div>
<input type="text" id="textinput"/>
```

CSS:

```
#clickme:not(.active) > .highlight {
    display: none;
}

#clickme.active > .normal {
    display: none;
}

.normal, .highlight {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

.normal {
    background: blue;
}

.highlight {
    background: red;
}
```

JS:

```
var clickme = $('#clickme');
var textinput = $('#textinput');

clickme.on('mousedown', function(e) {
    clickme.addClass('active');
    // ^-- comment this out and the click event starts working
});

clickme.on('mouseup', function(e) {
    clickme.removeClass('active');
    // ^-- comment this out and the click event starts working after the second click
});

clickme.on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    textinput.val(Date.now());
});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xLskk3po/14/

JSFiddle without JQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/xLskk3po/15/ It shows that it's not a JQuery problem.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this SO question: [When a mousedown and mouseup event don't equal a click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2111289/when-a-mousedown-and-mouseup-event-dont-equal-a-click) and it looks like my issue is similar to that. So I did something silly: I put a [transparent, absolutely positioned element on top](https://jsfiddle.net/uplink/80v16tmz/1/).

HTML:

```
<div id="clickme">
    <div class="normal"></div>
    <div class="highlight"></div>
    <div class="abs"></div> <!-- this is the absolute element, covering #clickme -->
</div>
<input type="text" id="textinput"/>
```

That fixed it.